# Authorization_RequestDenied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation while updating user password using Graph API

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a unique requirement to update the user passwords using Graph API. But, I have been getting Authorization_RequestDenied error.

```
{"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2022-10-06T22:45:14","request-id":"","client-request-id":""}}}
```

Below is my code:

```
public async Task UpdatePassword()
{
 Microsoft.Identity.Client.IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
              .Create("ClientId")
              .WithClientSecret("ClientSecret")
              .WithTenantId("TenantId")
              .Build();
            Microsoft.Graph.Auth.ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new Microsoft.Graph.Auth.ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphClient = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var newPassword = "NewComplexP@ss";

            var user = new Microsoft.Graph.User
            { 
                PasswordProfile = new Microsoft.Graph.PasswordProfile
                {
                    Password = newPassword,
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false
                } 
            };

            await graphClient  
               .Users["a4e3f2ce-054e-43e4-bbfd-547c44582a7"]
               .Request()
               .UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

I have permissions added like below in Azure AdB2c.

[image]

My question: despite adding all the permissions and using correct code(I assume) I am getting Authorization_RequestDenied error.

Am I missing anything? I highly appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are trying to update Azure AD B2C user password, please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/928309/azure-ad-b2c-update-password-from-graph-api-for-sp.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs as a background service or daemon without a signed-in user, you need also `User.ManageIdentities.All` application permission.

Comment: Just added User.Management.All both application and delegated permissions. Still same eror.