# Authorization_RequestDenied - Access to change password operation is denied

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am writing an API for user to reset self password. User is logged in an web application which calls MS Graph API.

While trying to self update password(I need to verify the current password too), I am getting below error:

```
code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Access to change password operation is denied."
```

Below is my code:

```
 private static async Task UpdatePassword(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenantId)
    {
        try
        { 
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            // Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
            var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

           
            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {

                // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
                    var authResult = await confidentialClient
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

                // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                })
                ); 

            await graphServiceClient.Users["9c704dfb-a3ea-528a-937c-d7da45ebcc7a"]
                .ChangePassword("OldPassword", "NewPassword").Request().PostAsync(); 

        }catch(Exception e)
        { 
        }
    }
```

I also saw /me endpoints but did not understand how to make that work in my scenario.

I appreciate any help, Thank you.

Comment: In short, what you write is wrong, because `change password` api doesn't support application type permission, but you used `xxx/.default` as the scope. What you should do to realize your requirement is that, you need to modify your web app application which integrating AAD and let users sign in, adding graph SDK code into that web app and write code to change password.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement: Writing an API for user to reset self password.

Background:  User is logged in an web application which calls MS Graph API.

If you want to create a stand alone web api which exposing a feature to let users update their password, it is impossible. Let's see the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions), it doesn't support application api permission. Pls note, application type not support means you can't write an api project to provide the ability because web api project is considered as a daemon application which only support AAD client credential flow, and client credential flow must use application permission. According your code snippet, you set the scope as `xxx/.default`, this means you are trying to use client credential flow.

[image]

We can only use `Delegated` api permission. According to the screenshot in your  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980762/authorization-requestdenied-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation), we can see you've given the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, so I consider you've had enough permissions. You can't realize this feature in a stand-alone api project, but you can do it in the web application which allows users to sign in by AAD.

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) for users sign in by integrating AAD into the web application. And I think you should have similar code in your web app(providing a login partial view, modify Startup.cs file and add configurations in appsettings.json), what you need to do is following the sample to add code about Graph SDK.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

[image]

And in your Controller, inject `GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient` and change password with code `await graphClient.Me.ChangePassword(currentPassword,newPassword).Request().PostAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *@Tiny Wang.* Although I have done the same via postman and it’s just a different approach to the solution of your issue.

To change user's password, you must add **Delegated** **`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`** permission for your application.

Please **note** that, the code you mentioned is using **`Client credentials flow`** that works with only **Application** permissions.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I granted below **`API permissions`** to the Azure AD application in my B2C tenant:

[image]

Now I generated access token using **client credentials flow** via Postman like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:client_id
grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret:client_secret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above **`token`** to call below query, I got **same** error:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/signed_in_user_id/changePassword
{
"currentPassword": "xxxxxx",
"newPassword": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to use ***interactive*** flows like Authorization Code, Username Password etc...

So, I generated access token using **Authorization Code flow** via Postman like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:client_id
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:client_secret
code:code
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
```

[image]

When I used the above **`token`** to call below query, password **changed** successfully like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/signed_in_user_id/changePassword
{
"currentPassword": "xxxxxx",
"newPassword": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Please **note** that, `/me/changePassword` endpoint is **same** as `/users/signed_in_user_id/changePassword` endpoint.

I tried using **`/me/changePassword`** endpoint and got same results as below:

[image]

**Code sample in C#**:

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var currentPassword = "xxxxxxx";
var newPassword = "xxxxxxxxxx";
await graphClient.Me
.ChangePassword(currentPassword,newPassword)
.Request()
.PostAsync();
```

**Reference:**
[user: changePassword - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

---

**Update**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
 client_id=<clientid>
 response_type=code
 redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
 response_mode=query
 scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
 state=12345
```

To generate Authorization Code flow, use this above code InPrivate mode and Sign into your account you get a code like this below. For [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is the code in the token request, and from where to get its value? Is it User's global id?

Comment: Please check this update answer